# C# with Assembler dll copying arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, assembly, dll, x86

I try to copy 1st element of 1st table to 1st element of 2nd table using c# and dll library in assembler.

My c# code

```
    [DllImport("mylib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern char wypmacasm(string table, ref string tab2);
 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            table= "German forces surrendered bla bla bla...."
            char aux= 'x';
            string p = "qwerty";

            aux=asmproc(table, ref  p);


            textBox6.Text = aux.ToString();
            textBox7.Text = p.ToString();
         }
```

and my asm code

```
asmproc proc tab: dword, tab2: dword

mov esi, tab
mov al, byte ptr[esi]   
ret 

asmproc endp
```

It works and in textBox6 i have char 'G'

but then i want to copy this elem to 2nd table

asm code

```
asmproc proc tab: dword, tab2: dword

    mov esi, tab
    mov al, byte ptr[esi]  
    mov edi, tab2
    mov byte ptr [edi], al

    ret 

    asmproc endp
```

and after ret program crashing with error :Unhandled exception at 0x771EED0B (ntdll.dll) in GUI.exe: 0xC0000374: Sterta została uszkodzona (parameters: 0x77224270).

Do you know how to copy element from 1st table to 2nd or what am I doing wrong in this case?

Comment: For starters, `esi` and `edi` are callee-saved registers, you should preserve their value. Better use `ecx` and `edx` (of course you don't even need two registers). Maybe that already fixes your problem.

Comment: You have to pass a byte array to the function not a string.  The assembly language doesn't know how to handle the class object string.

Comment: @jdweng it is not a probblem because of auto marshaling assembler know what it is and it works for reading tables but i dont know how to write to table value ;/ pushing and poping register doesn't make any difference

Comment: I used fixed(char* s = string)  and now it works